# Should I query everytime I need something from Realm/SQlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, architecture, realm

I am using `Realm/Sqllite` for storing my `user_id` along with `user names`, and in my friends section I am showing all of my friends name along with other information where unique key is this `user_id`.

And in my friends section I am using `recyclerview` to show all of my friends data,

Now I was just wondering suppose I have `100-200` friends list now to show user name what I can do is query every time for user_id from `Realm/Sqlite` in order to show the name of the user. OR I can just query all user_id list parallely and store them in a `HashMap`  and now for each `user_id` I can directly check in the hahsmap for getting user name.

I know second way will be faster but memory consuming also, and I checked the time taken by Realm/Sqlite for every query and it is around `1-2ms` that's why I was thinking as it is not that `slow` I can directly query from `Realm/Sqlite`.

Do anyone of you use the other technique or just query every time you need to get something from database?

Comment: Why not using Paging Architecture Component, along with Room, if you're using a SQLite database?! It will help you keep in your memory only the needed data, and  it will perform reads when the UI state require more data to be shown

Comment: @GregorioPalamà Even if I use pagination, I will have to query my db for each user_id everytime?

Comment: Paging performs query in bulk. So, the answer can't be "yes", but cannot be "no" either. It will perform queries, but for a whole page of users, not for the single user

Comment: So like is it Realm or is it SQLite?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Currently It is Realm, but wanted to know for both which type of solution do everyone use?

Comment: @GregorioPalamà Sorry but for geting user name I would have to query for user_id which I have made unique, now How can pagination help in this query?

Comment: I'm not getting your point, @SudhanshuGaur. When you query your database, you can get whatever you want, not only one field. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @GregorioPalamà Yes I know I can whatever I want from DB, but I am saying what is the use of pagination in this query?

Comment: The question was on which could be a good practice in the explained situation, considering memory usage and performances. Paging library actually is the officially suggested practice for this kind of situations. Please, refer to this link to have more informations: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/

Comment: @GregorioPalamà Yes I know paging library is better solution, also I will also use pagination in my friends list section, but I just wanted to ask should I opt for direct querying or use hahsmap for better performance? Pagination is definitely I am going to implement.

Comment: I think that using HashMap would lead you to a more complex solution. Since Paging already does what you need, just let it handle everything and opt for direct queries. It will let you have cleaner code for sure